# "String indices must be integers" error in pandas & yfinance - Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, datareader, yfinance

## Here is my code that I am using:

```
import warnings
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

date_from = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
date_to = datetime.date(2022, 12, 30)
tickerL = 'BTC-USD'
print("Comparing " + tickerL +" to...")
\#tickerL2 = \['AAPL'\]
tickerL2 = input('Now enter your comparison ticker:\\n')
tickerList = \[tickerL, tickerL2\]
print(tickerList)
\#tickerList = \['BTC-USD', 'AMZN', 'AAPL', 'CL=F', '^GSPC', '^DJI', 'GC=F'\]

\#fetch multiple asset data
def getMultiAssetData(tickerList, date_from, date_to):
def getData(ticker):
data = pdr.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", date_from, date_to)
return data

    datas = map(getData, tickerList)
    return pd.concat(datas, keys=tickerList, names=['Ticker', 'Date'])

sort=False
multiData = getMultiAssetData(tickerList, date_from, date_to)
df = multiData.copy()
\#print(df)

df = df.loc\[tickerL, :\]
df.tail()
```

**Now I keep getting this error and I don't know how to move forward:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 51, in \<module\>
multiData = getMultiAssetData(tickerList, date_from, date_to)
File "main.py", line 45, in getMultiAssetData
datas = list(map(getData, tickerList))
File "main.py", line 42, in getData
data = pdr.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", date_from, date_to)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/\_decorators.py", line 207, in wrapper
return func(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 370, in DataReader
return YahooDailyReader(
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 253, in read
df = self.\_read_one_data(self.url, params=self.\_get_params(self.symbols))
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py", line 153, in \_read_one_data
data = j\["context"\]\["dispatcher"\]\["stores"\]\["HistoricalPriceStore"\]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

**This script worked just fine a couple of months ago but I assume some of the packages got updated and now require different format.**

Comment: Somewhere or other, the json has changed format.  What used to be a dictionary is now a string.  Try pulling apart that `data =` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I figured it out. Yahoo finance changed a few things on their end which caused the issues. Here are the changes I made to the code to make it work: I defined data as: data = yf.download(tickerList, date_from, date_to)
print(data). Then I also deleted "yahoo" in: data = pdr.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", date_from, date_to)

Comment: I also added this:     
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()